# Oracle - Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to PL SQL. I have the following two tables: UserGame and Game.

```
CREATE TABLE Game (
    GameID INT NOT NULL,
    Name CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Description CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Publisher CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    AgeRating INT NOT NULL,
    ImageLink CHAR(100),
    WebsiteUrl CHAR(100),
    AverageRating FLOAT,
    OverallRanking INT,
    CONSTRAINT pkGameId
        PRIMARY KEY (GameID),
    CONSTRAINT AgeRating CHECK (AgeRating >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT OverallRankingMin CHECK (OverallRanking >= 0)
);

CREATE TABLE UserGame (
    PlayerID INT NOT NULL,
    GameID INT NOT NULL,
    Rating INT,
    RatingComment CHAR(100),
    LastPlayed DATE,
    HighestScore INT,
    InProgress CHAR(1),
    CONSTRAINT pkUserGame
        PRIMARY KEY (PlayerID, GameID),
    CONSTRAINT fkPlayerID
        FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID)
        REFERENCES Player (PlayerID),
    CONSTRAINT fkGameIdTer
        FOREIGN KEY (GameID)
        REFERENCES Game (GameID),
    CONSTRAINT RatingMin CHECK (Rating >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT RatingMax CHECK (Rating <= 5),
    CONSTRAINT HighestScore CHECK (HighestScore >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT InProgress CHECK (InProgress IN (0,1))
);
```

I would like to update the average rating of a game, every time a player updates a rating in UserGame.

This is what I came up with.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER averageUpdate
AFTER UPDATE OF Rating ON UserGame
BEGIN
  FOR r1 in (SELECT DISTINCT GameID FROM UserGame)
  LOOP
    UPDATE Game
    SET Game.AverageRating = (SELECT AVG(Rating) FROM UserGame WHERE GameID = r1.GameID GROUP BY GameID)
    WHERE Game.GameID = r1.GameID;
  END LOOP;
END averageUpdate;
```

But it does not work and I get this error:

```
Error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 900
Error occured in:
END LOOP
```

Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

---

It seems the code I had posted was correct, as confirmed by Justin Cave. There must be something wrong with my set-up then.

To make sure of this, I ran the queries using SQL Fiddle, with success.

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is the version of Oracle I am using: BANNER Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.6.0 - 64bit Production PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.6.0 - Production CORE 9.2.0.6.0 Production TNS for Solaris: Version 9.2.0.6.0 - Production NLSRTL Version 9.2.0.6.0 - Production

Comment: In a previous question you mentioned that you'd changed your Squirrel command separator character from `;` to `/`. Is that still the case when you are running these statements? And do you have a `/` after the trigger statement, either way?

Comment: Yes, I still used / as separator. And no, I did not add / at the end of the trigger. But when I do, it still does not run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that what you posted is actually what you're running?  It works fine for me (once I remove the foreign keys to tables that you haven't provided).

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Game (
  2      GameID INT NOT NULL,
  3      Name CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  4      Description CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  5      Publisher CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  6      AgeRating INT NOT NULL,
  7      ImageLink CHAR(100),
  8      WebsiteUrl CHAR(100),
  9      AverageRating FLOAT,
 10      OverallRanking INT,
 11      CONSTRAINT pkGameId
 12          PRIMARY KEY (GameID),
 13      CONSTRAINT AgeRating CHECK (AgeRating >= 0),
 14      CONSTRAINT OverallRankingMin CHECK (OverallRanking >= 0)
 15  );

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  CREATE TABLE UserGame (
  2      PlayerID INT NOT NULL,
  3      GameID INT NOT NULL,
  4      Rating INT,
  5      RatingComment CHAR(100),
  6      LastPlayed DATE,
  7      HighestScore INT,
  8      InProgress CHAR(1),
  9      CONSTRAINT fkGameIdTer
 10          FOREIGN KEY (GameID)
 11          REFERENCES Game (GameID),
 12      CONSTRAINT RatingMin CHECK (Rating >= 0),
 13      CONSTRAINT RatingMax CHECK (Rating <= 5),
 14      CONSTRAINT HighestScore CHECK (HighestScore >= 0),
 15      CONSTRAINT InProgress CHECK (InProgress IN (0,1))
 16* )
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER averageUpdate
  2  AFTER UPDATE OF Rating ON UserGame
  3  BEGIN
  4    FOR r1 in (SELECT DISTINCT GameID FROM UserGame)
  5    LOOP
  6      UPDATE Game
  7      SET Game.AverageRating = (SELECT AVG(Rating) FROM UserGame WHERE GameID = r1.GameID GROUP BY GameID)
  8      WHERE Game.GameID = r1.GameID;
  9    END LOOP;
 10  END averageUpdate;
 11  /

Trigger created.
```

Can you cut and paste from a SQL*Plus session just as I did here showing exactly what you are doing?

This doesn't have any impact on your current question.  But I would **strongly** suggest that you not use `char(100)` or `float` data types in this data model.  All these strings are variable length so you should be using `varchar2`.  `char` is a fixed-width data type.  A `char(100)` will always store exactly 100 bytes of data.  If your actual data is less than that, Oracle will add spaces at the end.  If you try to search for a particular value in the table and you end up with `char` comparison semantics, you'll need to ensure that the search string is space-padded to 100 bytes.  A `varchar2` is a variable-width data type.  It uses only as much space as is required for the actual data.  It doesn't do pointless and wasteful space-padding of data.  And you never need to worry about space-padding search strings.

I can also all but guarantee that you want your ratings to be `number` data types of some length and precision, not `float`.  Floating point numbers are inherently imprecise so an game that might average a score of 4.4 might be represented in a float as 4.3999999999865 or 4.4000000000107 (making the numbers up).  It's very unlikely that is the sort of score that your users want to see.  If you use a `number(4,3)`, you'll get 3 decimal digits of precision and you won't have to deal with errors (or imprecision if you prefer) in the least significant bits of the data.  A game that averages a score of 4.4 will have a value of 4.4 not something very very close to 4.4.

From a performance standpoint, I would strongly suggest that you not use a trigger to meet this requirement.  Particularly not a trigger that recomputes the score for every game every time any game gets rated.  That will not scale well and you will be spending gobs of time constantly recalculating scores.  Assuming you need to store the computed score, you probably want it to be refreshed periodically not immediately when a rating is entered.  If you do want to recompute the score every time a game is rated, only recompute the score for the game that was rated not for every game in the system.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Thanks for the catch!  That was quite the brain freeze.

Comment: Justin, again thank you for your help. I do not understand your first point regarding the data types. CHAR(100) is used for the comment on the rating. The Rating from UserGame is INT and the average that is derived from it (in Game) is FLOAT. Regarding your second point, I do take note. I had the same idea myself, but this database is not a production database, but a simple exercise I am working on. I wanted to trigger the update of the average rating for every update in UserGame, so as to be able to test that I was able to implement a trigger in PL SQL.

Comment: @lcazarre - I've expanded my answer.  This is not the sort of thing that I would use a trigger to implement in the first place, though, so it's not a particularly good exercise particularly for someone just learning PL/SQL.  You'll be much happier if you learn the language by doing things that make sense than by trying to do things in a way that the tools/ language aren't designed for.

Comment: I deleted all the tables and started from sratch again. This is what I get: Query 1 of 6, Rows read: 0, Elapsed time (seconds) - Total: 0.154, SQL query: 0.154, Reading results: 0

Query 2 of 6, Rows read: 0, Elapsed time (seconds) - Total: 0.131, SQL query: 0.131, Reading results: 0
Warning:   Warning: execution completed with warning
SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 17110

Query 3 of 6, Rows read: 0, Elapsed time (seconds) - Total: 0.108, SQL query: 0.108, Reading results: 0
Error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 900
Error occured in:
END LOOP

Comment: Could this be because of the version I am using again?

Comment: @lcazarre - I don't see anything that would obviously not work in the antiquated version of Oracle you're using.  I would be much more suspicious that it is something that your IDE is doing which is why I asked if you can do a copy and paste from a SQL*Plus session.  Your tool should also have a way to display the specific error and the line number of the error but I have no idea where that would be.  That's another reason that it's useful to use SQL*Plus.

Comment: Ok, I'll install SQL*Plus then. I'll try tomorrow morning as it is quite late in the UK already. I thank you very much. You have been very helpful.

Comment: I tested my queries using SQL Fiddle (see screenshot) and you are right that it does work. I am not sure what is going on with my set-up (antiquated Oracle version + Squirrel). I guess I will need to find an alternative for my project (our professor also suggests MySQL)...